# How to do another action, but still show the same url in browser in cakephp

Tags: php, html, css, cakephp

I want to call another action in cakephp . I want to run all the code in the action and render the view of that action. I know this can be done using `$this->requestAction()`, but the problem here is that it is not setting my title for the page which im doing in the called action. And i don't want to use redirect because it changes the url in my browser(ie it sends http 302).

Comment: You can call an action just like a function. You can render that action's view the way bfavaretto suggests.

Answer (score 0):

From inside any action, you can manually render any view using `$this->render` (see [api docs](http://api.cakephp.org/class/controller#method-Controllerrender)). Of course, you'll have to `set` the variables required on the other view beforehand.

Comment: i want to run the action logic in the other action. this action is just doing a small logic and then it should call the other action.

Comment: You could just call the other action with `$this->actionName()`.

Comment: It's possible to manually instantiate the other controller, and then call the other action, but that sounds like a terrible hack... Let's wait to see if someone else has a better idea.

Comment: Put that logic you want to run in component if you want to share code across controllers.